Timed out queries in Query Store (SQL Server)
I'm trying to find out timed out queries in Query store for production database .
I received logs from application site where for sure there was 5 timed out queries in short time window but somehow all queries in Query store are marked as completed during that time.
(I search for queries by longest duration during that time)
I'm a junior database admin and if anyone has any good tips for this, or how you investigate issues like that - any information would be appreciated.

I wrote a comment for the question with a mentioning the Article but my comment deleted. Dear administrators could you look - answer why the comment deleted. ?

You can use my stored procedure, sp_QuickieStore to look for aborted queries.
EXEC dbo.sp_QuickieStore
    @database_name = 'your database name',
    @start_date = 'your start date',
    @end_date = 'your end date',
    @execution_type_desc = N'Aborted';


What sort of timeout? There are levels to it.

There is a connection timeout where the application cannot even reach the server/database
There is a query compilation timeout. These don't show in Query Store
Query execution timeout. These should be in Query Store*. Use one of the community tools or look into the DMV sys.query_store_runtime_stats where execution_type = 3 /* aborted */

* Except when they aren't. Like Query Store being in read-only mode, the queries being killed, etc.

Erik's stored proc given above is amazing. I follow him and Brent closely and there's a lot to learn from them.
However, in case as a junior DBA if you are not able to install the proc given above, you might want to try the query given below. This has served me well in similar situations.
You can modify the predicate (WHERE clause) as required.
I got this query initially from (as far as I recall) Erin Stellato, have modified this to my requirements.
Look out for her articles and videos to enhance your knowledge on Query Store. It would really help understand this subject.
SELECT [qsq].[query_id], 
       [qst].[query_text_id], 
       [qsq].[query_hash], 
       [qsp].[query_plan_hash], 
       [qsp].[plan_id], 
       [qsq].[object_id], 
       [rs].[runtime_stats_interval_id], 
       [rs].[execution_type], 
       CASE 
            WHEN [rs].[execution_type] = 3 THEN 'Client Initiated Aborted Execution' 
            WHEN [rs].[execution_type] = 4 THEN 'Exception aborted execution' 
            WHEN [rs].[execution_type] = 0 THEN 'Regular execution (successfully finished)' 
            ELSE 'Unknown' 
       END AS [Execution_Type_Desc], 
      [rs].[min_duration], 
      [rs].[max_duration], 
      [rs].[first_execution_time], 
      [rs].[last_execution_time], 
      [rsi].[start_time] as [interval_start_time], 
      [rsi].[end_time] as [interval_end_time], 
      [rs].[count_executions], 
      [rs].[avg_duration], 
      [rs].[max_duration], 
      [rs].[avg_cpu_time], 
      [rs].[max_cpu_time], 
      [rs].[avg_logical_io_reads], 
      [rs].[avg_rowcount], 
      [rs].[max_query_max_used_memory], 
      [rs].[avg_query_max_used_memory], SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(qst.query_sql_text, CHAR(13),''), CHAR(10), ''), 1, 256) as [Partial_Query_Text] 
      FROM [sys].[query_store_query] [qsq] 
      JOIN [sys].[query_store_query_text] [qst] ON [qsq].[query_text_id] = [qst].[query_text_id] 
      JOIN [sys].[query_store_plan] [qsp] ON [qsq].[query_id] = [qsp].[query_id] 
      JOIN [sys].[query_store_runtime_stats] [rs] ON [qsp].[plan_id] = [rs].[plan_id] 
      JOIN [sys].[query_store_runtime_stats_interval] [rsi] ON [rs].[runtime_stats_interval_id] = [rsi].[runtime_stats_interval_id] 
    WHERE  [rs].[execution_type] in (3, 4) 
        -- AND [qsq].[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('nameofstoredproc')
    ORDER BY [qsq].[query_id], [qsp].[plan_id], [rs].[max_cpu_time] desc, [rs].[max_query_max_used_memory] desc, [rs].[runtime_stats_interval_id]; GO    

